# Ensemble averaging with non-identical (time) stamps

Tags: plotting, time-series, averages

I have data which could be interpreted as time series, but with non-identical time stamps.
Their format is:

```
xVal = {{x1,x2,x3}, {x4,x5,x6}, ...}
yVal = {{y1,y2,y3}, {y4,y5,y6}, ...}
```

where x1 and x4 (and all the other indexes of x values) may not coincide. Then I plot all this lists in yVal in dependence on xVal like this

```
 ListPlot[
 Table[Table[{xValues[[i, j]], yValues[[i, j]]}, {j, 
    Length[xValues[[i]]]}], {i, Length[xValues]}], 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Plot of two lists against each other"]
```

[image: Result of the comand]

The question is: Can I create ensemble average of these datasets and plot it?

Answer (score 1):

After a few hours of trying I came to the next solution:

1. To flatten data

```
   flattenedXValues = Flatten[x, 1];

   flattenedYValues = Flatten[y, 1];
```

2. Function which does what I want

```
  TimeRegression[x_, y_, n_] := Module[{xPoints, yVals = {}},
     minX = Min[x];
          maxX = Max[x];
     xinter = 
      Table[N[{minX + (i - 1)*(maxX - minX)/n, 
         minX + i*(maxX - minX)/n}], {i, Range[1, n]}];
     For[i = 1, i <= Length[xinter], i++,
      indexes = 
       Flatten@Position[
         x, _?(IntervalMemberQ[Interval[xinter[[i]]], #] &)];
      yMean = If[Length[indexes] > 0, Mean[y[[indexes]]], Null];
      yStd = 
       If[Length[y[[indexes]]] < 2, Null, 
        StandardDeviation[y[[indexes]]]];
      AppendTo[yVals, Around[yMean, yStd]];
      ];
     xPoints = 
      MapThread[
       Around, {Mean /@ xinter, 
        ConstantArray[(maxX - minX)/n, Length[xinter]]}];
     {xPoints, yVals}
     ]
```

3. After I have something like this:
   [image]

Is there a way maybe to do it easier?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
xVal = {{x1, x2, x3}, {x4, x5, x6}};
yVal = {{y1, y2, y3}, {y4, y5, y6}};

Transpose[{Mean /@ xVal, Mean /@ yVal}]
```

> {{1/3 (x1 + x2 + x3), 1/3 (y1 + y2 + y3)}, {1/3 (x4 + x5 + x6),
> 1/3 (y4 + y5 + y6)}}

Comment: No, not exactly. I posted below, what exactly I wanted.